# i have an editable li content that i wrap with span, but i am having issues on how to set limited characters when i edit the content

Tags: jquery

Here is the code; how can i limit the characters?

```
$("ul").on('click', 'span[data-id="editable-list-item"]', function(event){
    var $input = $('<input type="text" data-id="editable-list-item">');
    $input.val($(this).html());
    $(this).replaceWith($input);
    $input.focus();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Then

```
$("ul").on('focusout', 'input[data-id="editable-list-item"]', function() {
    var $span = $('<span data-id="editable-list-item">');
    $span.html($(this).val());
    $(this).replaceWith($span);
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: bind event keypress

Comment: please how will i bind it?

Comment: i need the code

Comment: Add a maxlength attribute to the input - <input type="text" maxlength="20"...